# Python Algorithm for finding hidden matches

Tags: python, algorithm, hashmap, list-comprehension, sudoku

I am trying to write a python program to solve a Sudoku board using human standard algorithms (i.e. no entirely bruteforced solution) and have been having trouble with finding an algorithm to manage [hidden doubles, triples, and quads](https://www.thonky.com/sudoku/hidden-pairs-triples-quads). For the sake of this question I am representing the board with a list of lists of lists, with a 2d list representing the Sudoku board, and each square represented as a list of possible values,

i.e.

```
[[[1,2,3],[4],[5]],
 [[2,6],[8,9],[7]],
 [[6,9],[1,2],[6,8]]]
```

So an example of a hidden pair in a row would be that for this row

```
[[1,3,7,8],[1,3,7,8],[2],[4],[3,5,7,9],[1,3,5,8,9],[6],[1,3],[1,8]]
```

The 5 and 9 at index 4 and 5 would be a hidden pair and after running the function would output this

```
[[1,3,7,8],[1,3,7,8],[2],[4],[5,9],[5,9],[6],[1,3],[1,8]]
```

What way would be the best to go about this?

While I've been able to implement working functions for pairs without other values the addition of other values has me stumped. I have heard that hashmaps could be useful for this sort of problem, but I don't have any experience with that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you recognize your 'hidden pair' yourself? Describe the process very accurately, and you'll (almost) have your code...

Comment: When finding a hidden pair myself I look through and recognize that there there is a pair that is only in two cells, however I'm unsure of how to implement that into my code without an amount of repetition that seems suboptimal; i.e. iterate through for each value to see if there is any values with only two instances and then check if there are any common values within those two. That would mean for pairs there is a minimum of 81 cycles, I was mostly asking this question to see if there is a better/less naive approach

Comment: Computers are very fast.  In my solve-like-a-human Sudoku, I keep track of what values are still unplaced, for each row, column, and box.  Then for each row, column, and box, I check every pair of unplaced values to see if its a hidden pair.  Get the code working first.  Worry about optimization later.

Comment: Personally I don't look for hidden pairs/triples etc. Wherever there's a hidden pair there must be "naked" (to use the terminology from your linked website) pairs/triples etc. Processing them will make the hidden pair naked too. For your sample data, you have  a naked quad `[1,3,7,8],[1,3,7,8],[1,3],[1,8]`, factoring those values out of the other cells leaves you with `[5,9], [5,9]` which is now a naked pair.